# google calendar libraries conflict with Evernote SDK on Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, evernote

I have created a Google Calendar sample application from following  [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android). The app runs well here. Then I want to integrate with Evernote SDk.

Here are my build.gradle dependences

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-sdk:2.0.0-RC2'
}
```

When I try to run the app this error appears:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Any Help ?

Comment: You might want to delete your build directory under the 'app' folder, then try to rebuild.

Comment: I tried to rebuild more than one time and the same error appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this exception by applying "Multidex"